# Simple Mod Rewrite .htaccess solution needed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Why can't the two rewrite rules work together and how to fix?

I'm trying to get wwww.mydomain.com/wordpress to wwww.mydomain.com/pages/wordpress.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks,

Comment: I am a little unsure what you want to accomplish. Wordpress uses the url that is displayed in the browser to display what is on the screen. All wordpress related things are channeled through index.php. If you randomly change the url, wordpress will stop working afaik.

Comment: I'm trying to create sub pages outside of wordpress, and have nothing todo with wordpress except being installed in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

You want the new rule *before* any of the wordpress rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(.*)$ /pages/$1.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The wordpress rule routes *everything* to index.php, including whatever it was you're trying to match.

Comment: Thanks I've given that a try and it hasn't worked for me, both the homepage and the sub pages are broken now - any ideas? Thank you